# What is the use of the "-O" flag for running Python?

Tags: python, assert, assertion

Python can run scripts in optimized mode ([`python -O`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonoptimize#cmdoption-O)) which turns off debugs, removes [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert) statements, and IIRC it also removes docstrings.

However, I have not seen it used. Is `python -O` actually used? If so, what for?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It saves a small amount of memory, and a small amount of disk space if you distribute any archive form containing only the `.pyo` files.  (If you use `assert` a lot, and perhaps with complicated conditions, the savings can be not trivial and can extend to running time too).

So, it's definitely not *useless* -- and of course it's being used (if you deploy a Python-coded server program to a huge number N of server machines, why *ever* would you want to waste N * X bytes to keep docstrings which nobody, ever, would anyway be able to access?!). Of course it would be better if it saved even more, but, hey -- waste not, want not!-)

So it's pretty much a no-brainer to keep this functionality (which is in any case trivially simple to provide, you know;-) in Python 3 -- why add even "epsilon" to the latter's adoption difficulties?-)

Answer (score 69):

python -O does the following currently:

- completely ignores asserts
- sets the special builtin name `__debug__` to False (which by default is True)

and when called as python -OO

- removes docstrings from the code

I don't know why everyone forgets to mention the `__debug__` issue; perhaps it is because I'm the only one using it :) An `if __debug__` construct creates no bytecode at all when running under `-O`, and I find that very useful.

Answer (score 7):

Prepacked software in different Linux distributions often comes byte-compiled with -O. For example, this if from [Fedora packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging/Python) for python applications:

> In the past it was common practice to %ghost .pyo files in order to save a small amount of space on the users filesystem. However, this has two issues: 1. With SELinux, if a user is running python -O [APP] it will try to write the .pyos when they don't exist. This leads to AVC denial records in the logs. 2. If the system administrator runs python -OO [APP] the .pyos will get created with no docstrings. Some programs require docstrings in order to function. On subsequent runs with python -O [APP] python will use the cached .pyos even though a different optimization level has been requested. The only way to fix this is to find out where the .pyos are and delete them.
>
> The current method of dealing with pyo files is to include them as is, no %ghosting.

Answer (score 3):

Removing assertions means a *small* performance benefit, so you could use this for "release" code. Anyway nobody uses it because many Python libraries are open sourced and thus the `help()` function should work.

So, as long as there isn't any *real* optimization in this mode, you can ignore it.

Comment: "Removing assertions means a small performance benefit" That depends on what you put in your assertions. If you use assertions as a debugging aid (as it was intended) to verify your assumptions, you might actually make heavy checks (such as, for example matrix inequality).
In that case, you absolutely do not want those to be run in production code

Comment: When one runs `python -O` or `python3 -O`, the `help()` function still works; so the “nobody uses it because…” is invalid/based on a faulty assumption.