# What are the implications of running python with the optimize flag?

Tags: python, optimization

What does Python do differently when running with the `-O` (optimize) flag?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`assert` statements are completely eliminated, as are statement blocks of the form `if __debug__: ...` (so you can put your debug code in such statements blocks and just run with `-O` to avoid that debug code).

With `-OO`, in addition, docstrings are also eliminated.

Comment: @RamRachum Yes. I've submitted an edit to this question to provide more details.

Comment: FYI, when -OO is used in the shebang header, it often comes with an explicit path to the Python interpreter. This can throw you off if you are used to running scripts in an "env" like virtualenv - import errors and such, until you realize what's happening. To be clear, that's an effect of the path, not -OO.

Answer (score 35):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files):

> - You can use the `-O` or `-OO` switches on the Python command to reduce the size of a compiled module. The `-O` switch removes assert statements, the `-OO` switch removes both assert statements and __doc__ strings. Since some programs may rely on having these available, you should only use this option if you know what you’re doing. “Optimized” modules have an `opt-` tag and are usually smaller. Future releases may change the effects of optimization.
> - A program doesn’t run any faster when it is read from a `.pyc` file than when it is read from a `.py` file; the only thing that’s faster about `.pyc` files is the speed with which they are loaded.

So in other words, almost nothing.

Answer (score 10):

From [What does the -O flag do?](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/586185-what-does-o-flag-do)

> It somewhat depends on the Python
>   version. To find out precisely what it
>   does, search the source code for
>   Py_OptimizeFlag. In 2.5, it
>
> - causes the interpreter to load .pyo files, not .pyc files (in .zip files,
>     just makes .pyo preferred over .pyc)
> - causes `__debug__` to have a value of 0
> - ignores assert statements in source code
> - treats `__debug__` statically as being 0
> - causes the byte code generator to save .pyo files, not .pyc

Answer (score 9):

As answered in [python optimization mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055557):

python -O does the following currently:

- completely ignores asserts
- sets the special builtin name `__debug__` to False (which by default is True)

and when called as python -OO

- removes docstrings from the code

I don't know why everyone forgets to mention the `__debug__` issue; perhaps it is because I'm the only one using it :) An `if __debug__` construct creates no bytecode at all when running under `-O`, and I find that very useful.

Comment: Note that this answer is an exact copy of my answer in [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055557/python-optimized-mode) question from Jan 13, 2010; in his answer to that question, Alex Martelli didn't mention the `if __debug__` construct, and that is why my answer here seems to be out-of-place (my “why everyone forgets to mention”).