# local flag in python module for debugging purposes

Tags: python, debugging, optimization

I would like to have a local debug flag defined in every module of my project and to use it in combination with **debug** variable in order to be able to do partial debugging. For example f i want to debug module mod1 i would define

mod1_dflag = True

and then in every debug section i would like to use:

```
if __debug__:
    if mod1_dflag:
        debug code block
```

If I do something like this, will Python optimizer ommit completely outer if statement?
To be more precise, what will be this code turned into after I run the script with -O flag?

The solution is suggested by Oliver Bestwalter and could be found at:
[stackoverflow.com/a/2830411/2626627](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2830411/2626627)

Comment: Why don't you just set or unset the <module>.___debug__ flag for certain modules completely dynamically during your test setup (e.g. by reading a list of modules from a configuration file)? Then you could leave the production code alone.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that every module has it's own built-in __debug__ flag.

Comment: That was not my main point: for your purpose you don't even need to use an inbuilt flag. The main thing I was trying to say, is that you can do that dynamically for every module on test setup instead of having to add it to your production code.

Comment: Can somebody just say will this code be ommited or not after optimization?

Comment: You can try this yourself ... and it's in the interwebs already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2830411/2626627

Answer (score 0):

`__debug__` is by default `True`. It's only set to `False` when python with run in *optimized mode* - which people often not do.

The optimize command line arguments:

```
-O     : optimize generated bytecode slightly; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x
-OO    : remove doc-strings in addition to the -O optimizations
```

The best thing you could do is use an environment variable. Eg:

```
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG')

if DEBUG:
    do debug stuff
```

Then you can do `export DEBUG=y` in your shell or `set DEBUG=y` on windows before running your app to enable debug mode.