# Does converting an interpreted script to an executable increase speed?

Tags: python, performance, compilation, py2exe

In general I'm curious, does using a utility that converts a non-exe to an exe increase speed? It's my understanding that they just package the interpreter inside the exe.

In specific, if you have a python script and use py2exe on it, does the resulting executable run faster than the .py? My boss seems to have the assumption it does but I'm not so sure.

Especially when dealing with multiple modules. For example say you have modules `first.py` and `second.py`. You compile them all to executables. When they were .py they `second.py` could be called as

```
from second import main
main()
```

Now that they're executables you have to start a new process, which surely is slower?

`subproccess.call(["second.exe"], shell=True)`

Do I understand this correctly? Or does `import`ing from another python module actually start a new instance of the python interpreter or something?

In our case the target platform is always Windows.

Comment: How about testing it and getting some concrete numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boss is misinformed. All py2exe does is package your program into a self-contained package capable of running without dependencies. It is still the same bytecode running on the same interpreter (well, whatever one is packaged).

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2830413/1798683) for about all of the "optimization" you can get out of using -o flags.

Also, yes, definitely run some benchmarks to confirm for yourself.