# Unexpected PyCharm run vs debug behavior for __debug__

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following python code:

```py
def main():
    if __debug__:
        print("debug mode")
    else:
        print("non debug")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

No matter whether I run the file or debug it, it always prints "debug mode". this is not what I would have expected. My debug block is computationally costly, so I Would prefer to only run it on my development machine if I am in debug mode in pycharm (and never in prod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My debug block is computationally costly, so I Would prefer to only run it on my development machine if I am in debug mode in pycharm (and never in prod).

This is exactly why the optimization flag exist in Python.

## Use optimization flag

Because `__debug__` is true when you don't use the optimization flag.

Add this to the run configuration "Interpreter options": `-O`

You can get the same behavior with python in CLI:

```py
$ python file.py
debug mode
$ python -O file.py
Non debug
```

More details on `-O` flag: [What is the use of the "-O" flag for running Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2167639/6251742)

Comment: I see I phrased the question poorly, but you answered what I asked. What I Really look for is whether I can change the default way in which pycharm runs (i.e. have the `-O` flag added by default): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384689/pycharm-change-default-run-behaviour-to-include-o-flag

Comment: `-O` should be in prod like scripts only, in pycharm, you should run in debug mode, no?