# How can this Raku comparison be improved performance-wise?

Tags: performance, generator, primes, raku

I wanted to do some comparison between Python and Raku while also learning Raku.

Originally I wanted a much bigger script, but since the difference is already huge, I'll ask for guidance now.

I tried to faithfully translate this Python script while applying Raku learnings that shouldn't hurt performance:

```py
from collections import deque
from itertools import count, islice


def primes_wheel():
    yield 2
    composites = {}
    for candidate in count(3, step=2):
        prime = composites.pop(candidate, 0)
        if prime:
            while True:
                candidate += prime + prime
                if candidate not in composites:
                    composites[candidate] = prime
                    break
        else:
            composites[candidate * candidate] = candidate
            yield candidate


def last(itr):
    return deque(itr, 1).pop()


LENGTH = 99999

print(last(islice(primes_wheel(), 0, LENGTH)))
```

I arrived at this:

```
sub primes_wheel {
    my %composite;

    gather {
        take 2;
        for 3,5…* -> $candidate is copy {
            my $prime = %composite{$candidate}:delete;
            if $prime.defined {
                loop {
                    $candidate += $prime + $prime;
                    if not %composite{$candidate}:exists {
                        %composite{$candidate} = $prime;
                        last;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                %composite{$candidate * $candidate} = $candidate;
                take $candidate;
            }
        }
    }
}

constant LENGTH = 99999;

say primes_wheel[LENGTH - 1];
```

The results are really not in Raku's favour (`-OO` doesn't make much of a difference for Python, but `--optimize=3` makes Raku slower):

```
% hyperfine 'raku primes.raku' 'python -OO primes.py'
Benchmark 1: raku primes.raku
  Time (mean ± σ):      4.953 s ±  0.050 s    [User: 4.986 s, System: 0.040 s]
  Range (min … max):    4.899 s …  5.036 s    10 runs

Benchmark 2: python -OO primes.py
  Time (mean ± σ):     291.3 ms ±  13.8 ms    [User: 125.2 ms, System: 15.2 ms]
  Range (min … max):   266.4 ms … 315.9 ms    10 runs

Summary
  python -OO primes.py ran
   17.01 ± 0.82 times faster than raku primes.raku
```

Did I miss something or use stuff not in the right manner? I'd like for Raku to catch up. I'm interested in both performance improvements as well as Rakuisms.

---

#### Code translation question?

This is **not** a code translation question:

> a lot of questions in the […] tag which ask for the conversion of […] code to […]

I did the conversion **myself**, that was the fun of it! Here I'm asking why my result is so slow (i.e. how I can get it faster) and whether I'm using constructs the right way (i.e. something that contributes to the slow down).

Also I said that I'm open to hear about Rakuisms to improve it, that's not code translation.

@Karl Knechtel: I could even have left the Python part out completely as if if weren't a translation. It would have been the same question, maybe then you'd seen it. But I decided to keep it in, so that answers stay closer to it. Which is also why I don't accept [Elizabeth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77141051/581002) although it shows what you *should* be doing for production code. I have a feeling my Raku is doing something wrong—at least I hope so. I'd hope for an answer spotting that and giving me deeper understand. SO is about learning, right?

Having said that, neither "unclear what you're asking" nor “needs debugging details” from [your link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825) is applicable here IMHO.

Comment: We don't do code translation here; please only tag languages that are relevant to *understanding how to answer the question* - Python experts can't help you with Raku any more than anyone else, on average (I've been using Python for close to 20 years and I've never even heard of Raku before). Please explain clearly *what the code should do* instead of making reference to code in a different programming language. See also: [How should we tag code translation questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825)

Comment: But just for the record: Python's `-OO` flag has **nothing to do with** bytecode-level optimizations or really anything that would improve runtime performance in any meaningful sense: it [**only**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055557) discards docstrings and disables assertions (and other code *explicitly marked* as being for debugging using the `__debug__` built-in constant).

Comment: @primfaktor just for the record the Raku community is open to your questions. You won't find any of us foaming at the mouth to tell you what you're doing wrong, so if this gets closed feel free to visit us on IRC

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know about `-OO`, I spent quite some time in Python, too. But _not running_ assertions (that might lurk somewhere deeper) _would_ save time, wouldn't it? The only reason I added the parentheses so that certain users wouldn't rush to comment “You're running one with and one without!”

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @jubilatious1 It [_is_ Eratosthenes' sieve](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2023/my-favorite-prime-number-generator/). Just not with an array, because I want the infinite version—hard to allocate as an array.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, you should use the strengths of a programming language, and not try to mimic approaches from other languages.  In this case:

```
constant LENGTH = 99999;
my @primes = (^Inf).grep(*.is-prime);
say @primes[LENGTH - 1];
```

Or, if you're not really interested in the values inbetween:

```
say (^Inf).grep(*.is-prime).skip(LENGTH - 1).head;
```

This runs in about .56 seconds on my M1 MacMini.  However, this pipeline approach allows for hypering, using more than one CPU:

```
say (^Inf).hyper(batch => 2048).grep(*.is-prime).skip(99998).head;
```

This runs in about .24 seconds for me.  Minus the .11 startup overhead, that's about 3.5 times as fast.  Which isn't too bad on a 4 core machine.

Comment: Wow, impressive that that's in there! I need a working LSP to help with discoverability. You're right, I would use that provided functionality in production code. But I feel that would would not be a faithful translation anymore (like offloading some Python computation to a C extension).

Comment: @primfaktor, I think you have made a fair line by line conversion from Python to Raku ... I was surprised to see that Raku is 17x slower, but I would never expect it to be faster. Raku is not yet well optimised for speed - there is some hope that the recent RakuAST implementation will allow better introspection and thus better "jit" optimisations. Based on this answer from lizmat, since Raku rewritten to use the is-prime sub IS only ~2x slower on a 4 core machine (and that this hyper is amenable to concurrency) you need to upgrade to a 8 core machine and then Raku will be 2x faster!

Comment: ^^^ my previous comment has an important point which is not "go out and buy a new MacBook Pro", but that, unlike Python, raku has no GIL and today on modern high end machines is ALREADY 2x faster due ... and in a couple of years we will all have 8 core machines....

Comment: @librasteve I get your point, but if you double the cores from 4 to 8 you can only expect about double the speed, i.e. Raku's `is-prime` "cheat" on an otherwise unloaded 8 core would then roughly match Python's sieve of Eratosthene's Sieve performance on an otherwise unloaded single core.